# Parse Output for Python

Tags: python, regex, iteration

My software outputs these two types of output:

```
-rwx------ Administrators/Domain Users  456220672   0% 2018-04-16 16:04:40 E:\\_WiE10-18.0.100-77.iso

-rwxrwx--- Administrators/unknown        6677   0% 2018-04-17 01:33:23 E:\\program files\\cluster groups\\sql server (mssqlserver)\\logs\\progress-MOD-1523883344023-3001-Windows.log
```

I would like to get the file names from both outputs:

- `E:\\_WiE10-18.0.100-77.iso`, for the first one
- `E:\\program files\\cluster groups\\sql server (mssqlserver)\\logs\\progress-MOD-1523883344023-3001-Windows.log`, for the second one

If i use something like the code below, it won't work if the second parameter has spaces in it. It works if there aren't any spaces in the Domain Username.

```
for item in outputs:
    outputs.extend(item.split())
for item2 in [' '.join(outputs[6:])]:
    new_list.append(item2)
```

How can I get all the parameters individually, including the filenames?

Comment: E. g. with a regular expression like `\b[A-Z]:\\\\.+`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If regex is an option:

```
text = """-rwx------ Administrators/Domain Users  456220672   0% 2018-04-16 16:04:40 E:\\_WiE10-18.0.100-77.iso

-rwxrwx--- Administrators/unknown        6677   0% 2018-04-17 01:33:23 E:\\program files\\cluster groups\\sql server (mssqlserver)\\logs\\progress-MOD-1523883344023-3001-Windows.log"""

import re

for h in re.findall(r"^.*?\d\d:\d\d:\d\d (.*)",text,flags=re.MULTILINE):
    print(h)
```

Output:

```
E:\_WiE10-18.0.100-77.iso
E:\program files\cluster groups\sql server (mssqlserver)\logs\progress-MOD-1523883344023-3001-Windows.log
```

**Pattern explained:**

The pattern `r"^.*?\d\d:\d\d:\d\d (.*)"` looks for linestart `'^'` + as less anythings as possible `'.*?'` + the time-stamp `'\d\d:\d\d:\d\d '` followed by a space and captures all behind it till end of line into a group.

It uses the `re.MULTILINE` flag for that.

---

Edit:

Capturing the individual things needs some more capturing groups:

```
import re

for h in re.findall(r"^([rwexXst-]+) ([^0-9]+) +\d+.+? +(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}) (.*)",text,flags=re.MULTILINE):
#                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^
#                          flags     grpName                               datetime          filename
    for k in h:
        print(k)
    print("")
```

Output:

```
-rwx------
Administrators/Domain Users 
2018-04-16 16:04:40
E:\_WiE10-18.0.100-77.iso

-rwxrwx---
Administrators/unknown       
2018-04-17 01:33:23
E:\program files\cluster groups\sql server (mssqlserver)\logs\progress-MOD-1523883344023-3001-Windows.log
```

Comment: How can i get all parameters individually like if i only need permissions(first one) and date and time as well?

Comment: i got the first one :             for fileperm in re.findall(r"([^ ]+) .*",backup_files_val,flags=re.MULTILINE):
                print(fileperm)

Comment: @PetPan you would need more capturing groups. Look: https://regexr.com/3oart .. something along `'^([rwexXst-]+) ([^0-9]+) +\d+.+? +(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}) (.*)'`  - groups 1 to 4 will give you the different capturing groups.

Comment: if i may ask a final edit, how can i get the File_size as well along with all other details..? which in this case is : 456220672 and 6677

Comment: @PetPan look at the regex - the filesize is currently not captured: change regex to `re.findall(r"^([rwexXst-]+) ([^0-9]+) +(\d+) .+? +(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}) (.*)",text,flags=re.MULTILINE):`

Comment: i Slightly modified it to get the full filesize, your regex was missing + sign for the following ^([rwexXst-]+) ([^0-9]+) +(\d+).... now, its working, thanks again. cheers

Comment: the code breaks if the username has got number in it : let's say (peter2/domain users) this won't work with the current regex, how do i modify it to get it working?

Comment: @PetPan you can try to change `([^0-9]+) ` to `([^ ]+) `  - I think it should work out. Unless you can have spaces in this part as well ....

Answer (score 2):

You could use a regular expression like

```
\b[A-Z]:\\\\.+
```

Answer (score 1):

Aside from using regex, you can try something similar to this.

```
output = '-rwx------ ... 2018-04-16 16:04:40 E:\\\\_WiE10-18.0.100-77.iso'

drive_letter_start = output.find(':\\\\')
filename = output[drive_letter_start - 1:]
```

It looks for the first occurrence of `':\\'`and gets the drive letter before the substring (i.e. `':\\'`) and the full file path after the substring.

**EDIT**
Patrick Artner's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49965923/1116098) is better and completely answers OP's question compared to this answer. This only encompasses capturing the file path. I am leaving this answer here should anyone find it useful.